# How is it possible to save/download a barplot in R shiny?

Tags: r, download, shiny, bar-chart

I would like to save/download my `barplots` in shiny. I did it with `ggplot`, with `ggsave` and it was possible, but how can I do it for `barplot()`? My code in `ui.R` is:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      title = "", 
      status = "danger", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      plotOutput(outputId = "myPlotMdata1")
    ),

    box(
      title = "", 
      status = "danger", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      plotOutput(outputId = "myPlotMdata2")
    ),

    box(
      title = "", 
      status = "danger", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      plotOutput(outputId = "myPlotMdata3")
    ),

    box(
      title = "", 
      status = "danger", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      plotOutput(outputId = "myPlotMdata4")
    ),
    box(
      title = "Download", 
      status = "success", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 12,
      radioButtons("formatTopwords", "Document format", c("PNG"="png", "EPS"="eps", "PDF"="pdf"), inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton("downloadReportTopwords")
    )
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlotMdata1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(TopWords$lassoInfPos, las = 2, names.arg = TopWords$informedPos, main = "Informed Investor Top 15 positive words", ylab = "Lasso coefficient")
  })

  output$myPlotMdata2 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(TopWords$lassoNoisePos , las = 2, names.arg = TopWords$noisePos, main = "Noise Investor Top 15 positive words", ylab = "Lasso coefficient")
  })

  output$myPlotMdata3 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(TopWords$lassoInfNeg, las = 2, names.arg = TopWords$informedNeg, main = "Informed Investor Top 15 negative words", ylab = "Lasso coefficient")
  })

  output$myPlotMdata4 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(TopWords$lassoNoiseNeg, las = 2, names.arg = TopWords$noiseNeg, main = "Noise Investor Top 15 negative words", ylab = "Lasso coefficient")
  })

  fn <- reactive({paste("Plot",input$formatTopwords,sep = ".")})
  d <- reactive({input$formatTopwords})

  output$downloadReportTopwords <- downloadHandler(
    filename = fn,
    content = function(file) {
      #ggsave I use for another function, how can I save barplots here
      ggsave(file, device=d(), dpi = 600, width = 297, height = 210, units = "mm")
    }
  )
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You're app is not reproducible, there is no data and no barplots. Could you include some dummy data..

Comment: @SeGa check now. But the important task is the download of the plot. My dataframe includes 70.000 rows so I cant include dummy data

Comment: I know, but without a functioning app, everyone has to write his own dummy data to check if its working, except someone has a solution already. There is no need to add your data.frame, just create a random one, with maybe only one numeric column and just include one barplot. Thats gonna make it much easier to go through the code and focus on the important stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about EPS, but the following example works for PNG and PDF. You can create a plotting function, which you then call in your `renderPlot` and in the `downloadHandler`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

TopWords = data.frame(
  lassoInfPos = runif(100,1,100),
  lassoNoisePos = runif(100,1,50),
  lassoInfNeg = runif(100,1,20),
  lassoNoiseNeg = runif(100,1,10)
)

ui <- {dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = 6,
      plotOutput("myPlotMdata1"),
      plotOutput("myPlotMdata2")
    ),
    box(width = 6,
      plotOutput("myPlotMdata3"),
      plotOutput("myPlotMdata4")
    ),
    box(
      title = "Download", 
      status = "success", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 12,
      radioButtons("formatTopwords", "Document format", c("PNG"="png", "EPS"="eps", "PDF"="pdf"), inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton("downloadReportTopwords")
    )
  )
)}



barplot_func <- function(input, main) {
  barplot(input, las = 2, #names.arg = TopWords$informedPos, 
          main = main, ylab = "Lasso coefficient")
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlotMdata1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot_func(TopWords$lassoInfPos, "Informed Investor Top 15 positive words")
  })
  output$myPlotMdata2 <- renderPlot({
    barplot_func(TopWords$lassoNoisePos, "Informed Investor Top 15 positive words")
  })
  output$myPlotMdata3 <- renderPlot({
    barplot_func(TopWords$lassoInfNeg, "Informed Investor Top 15 negative  words")
  })
  output$myPlotMdata4 <- renderPlot({
    barplot_func(TopWords$lassoNoiseNeg, "Informed Investor Top 15 negative  words")
  })

  fn <- reactive({paste("Plot",input$formatTopwords,sep = ".")})
  d <- reactive({input$formatTopwords})

  output$downloadReportTopwords <- downloadHandler(
    filename = fn,
    content = function(file) {
      if (input$formatTopwords == "png") {
        png(file)
      } else if(input$formatTopwords == "pdf") {
        pdf(file)
      }
      par(mfrow=c(2,2))
      barplot_func(TopWords$lassoInfPos, "Informed Investor Top 15 positive words")
      barplot_func(TopWords$lassoNoisePos, "Informed Investor Top 15 positive words")
      barplot_func(TopWords$lassoInfNeg, "Informed Investor Top 15 negative  words")
      barplot_func(TopWords$lassoNoiseNeg, "Informed Investor Top 15 negative  words")
      dev.off() 
    }
  )
}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: perfect bro! it works nicely! thanks so much. But I am ploting 4 different barplots. is it also possible to download all together, like all in one page?

Comment: Yes you can, I just edited my answer, although thats the ugly way of doing that. But you can set par(mfrow()) to whatever you like and then add all the plots in there. But I would actually create a plotting function, which creates the barplot with certain arguments, then you would just have to call the function in the `renderPlot` function and in the `downloadHandler`.

Comment: I edited the answer. Its much nicer with a plotting function. :)

Comment: thanks so much, just perfect! Have a look on my other problem, where I cant solve it :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856951/subset-dataframe-and-plot-with-ggplot