# Subset Dataframe and plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, subset

I created a shiny app and need some help with the subset of my data. I insert a `dateRangeInput` where the client can filter between a start and end date. This filter is included into my ggplot code, so that the plot always automatically changes when a different date is selected. My problem is it does not filter based on the selected date, the data of `partC`. The problem is this line of code: `geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = OLS.Data[partC]), color="red")`. `partC` is a variable that connects to selectinputs to have access to my dataframe. Example: Client selects `input1 = Informed` and `input2 = Full`, `partC` makes `InformedFull` (which is the name of one column of my dataset) and so on. So `partC` is just a a connector of the two inputs, and this is my problem. If I put into my geom_line this code e.g `geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = InformedFull), color="red")`, instead the above everything works perfect, but I need it with partC.

Here is my ui.R code (only necessary part):

```
        box(
          title = "Controls-0", 
          status = "primary", 
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 3,
          height = 142,
          dateRangeInput("daterange", "SELECT DATE:", start = min(OLS.Data$Date), end = max(OLS.Data$Date))
        ), 

            box(
              title = "Investor Control", 
              status = "primary", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 3,
              selectInput("investor", label="Select Investor", choices = list("Informed" = "Informed", "Noise" = "Noise"), selected = "Informed")
            ),

            box(
              title = "Category Control", 
              status = "primary", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 3,
              selectInput("category", label="Select Category", choices = list("Full" = "Full", "Fact" = "Fact", "Fact Positive" = "Fact.Pos", "Fact Negative" = "Fact.Neg", "Emotions" = "Emotions", "Emotions Fact" = "EmotionsFact"), selected = "Full")
            ),
```

Update server.R with ggplot:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  partC = NULL

  makeReactiveBinding("partC")


  observeEvent(input$investor, { 
    partA<<-input$investor
    partA<<-as.character(partA)
  })

  observeEvent(input$category, { 
    partB<<-input$category
    partB<<-as.character(partB)
  })

  OLS.Data$InformedEmotionsFact <- as.numeric(as.character(OLS.Data$InformedEmotionsFact))
  OLS.Data$NoiseEmotionsFact <- as.numeric(as.character(OLS.Data$NoiseEmotionsFact))

  output$myPlotVisu <- renderPlot({
    partC<-as.character(paste(partA,partB,sep=""))

    OLS.Data %>%
      select(partC, NYSE,Date,Sector) %>%
      filter(Date >= input$daterange[1], Date <= input$daterange[2]) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = NYSE)) +
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle(paste(input$investor,input$category,sep = "")) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold")) +
      labs(x="Time",y="Return S&P500") +
      geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = OLS.Data[partC]), color="red")
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you assign partA/partB to the global environment, and even twice. You dont need to do that. I created an `reactiveValues` object instead, where you store the values (partA, partB and partC). Then you can use them wherever you want in your app.

Maybe the following example will help you with your code. I created some dummy data for it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

## DATA #######################
DateSeq = seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1911/1/1"), "days")

OLS.Data = data.frame(
  ID = 1:length(DateSeq),
  Date = DateSeq,
  NoiseEmotionsFact = sample(1:100,length(DateSeq), T),
  InformedEmotionsFact = sample(100:1000,length(DateSeq), T),
  InformedFull = sample(10:1000,length(DateSeq), T),
  NoiseFull = sample(50:5000,length(DateSeq), T),
  NoiseFact = sample(1:15,length(DateSeq), T),  
  NoiseFact.Pos = sample(100:110,length(DateSeq), T),
  NoiseFact.Pos = sample(10:200,length(DateSeq), T)
)


## UI #######################
ui <- {dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    box(
      title = "Controls-0", 
      status = "primary", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 3,
      height = 142,
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "SELECT DATE:", start = min(OLS.Data$Date), end = max(OLS.Data$Date))
    ),
    box(
      title = "Alpha",
      sliderInput("alphaVisu", label = "Alpha :", min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.4, step = 0.1)
    ),

    box(
      title = "Investor Control", 
      status = "primary", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 3,
      selectInput("investor", label="Select Investor", 
                  choices = list("Informed" = "Informed", "Noise" = "Noise"), selected = "Informed")
    ),

    box(
      title = "Category Control", 
      status = "primary", 
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      width = 3,
      selectInput("category", label="Select Category", 
                  choices = list("Full" = "Full", "Fact" = "Fact", "Fact Positive" = "Fact.Pos", 
                                 "Fact Negative" = "Fact.Neg", "Emotions" = "Emotions", 
                                 "Emotions Fact" = "EmotionsFact"), selected = "Full")
    )
  )
)}

## SERVER #######################
server <- function(input, output) {

  ## Reactive Values ############
  parts <- reactiveValues(partA=NULL, partB=NULL, partC=NULL)

  ## Observe Events ############
  observeEvent(input$investor, { 
    parts$partA <- as.character(input$investor)
  })
  observeEvent(input$category, { 
    parts$partB <- as.character(input$category)
  })

  ## Plot ############
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({

    parts$partC <- as.character(paste(parts$partA, parts$partB,sep=""))

    OLS.Data.filtered <-  OLS.Data %>%
      filter(Date >= input$daterange[1], Date <= input$daterange[2])

    req(OLS.Data.filtered)

    OLS.Data.filtered %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = ID)) +
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle(paste("input$investor","input$category",sep = "")) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold")) +
      labs(x="Time",y="Return S&P500") +

      geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = OLS.Data.filtered[parts$partC]), color="red", 
                alpha = rep(as.numeric(input$alphaVisu), nrow(OLS.Data.filtered[parts$partC])))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: SeGa man your are a genius! Bro thanks so much for your help! just perfect, i was working on the problem 3 days. thanks so much!!!

Comment: One other quick question. I am trying to put a alpha to my ggplot where the client can play with the transparency of the lines. If i put this `+ geom_line(alpha = input$alphaVisu)` i get this error: `Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (73986): alpha`

Comment: any idea SeGa ?? thats the last think I need to fix bro!

Comment: I edited my answer. As the sliderInput only creates 1 value for `alphaVisu`, I just repeat the value in `geom_line` for the amount of rows in `OLS.Data.filtered[parts$partC]`.

Comment: SeGa god bless you bro! just perfect!!!!!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helps :)